# Save image and encrypt it so that no one can access

Tags: ios, image, encryption, digital-signature

Currently I'm using this [tutorial](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/tutorial-drawing-to-the-screen.132024/) now but I need some help in saving it to an image. For security purposes, is it possible to encrypt the file. And also, only my app will access the said file. I'm asking for help for saving it as image but encrypted, as well as how can I access the encrypted file. Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what you've done to try and solve the problem; it currently reads like a request for code. Please share your attempted implementation and explain how it fails to meet your requirements.

Comment: Actually, I am asking for a code. I have used the tutorial above for writing the signature, and since I am new in ios development, I don't have any idea with this, that is why I am asking if one could help me clear this or give me code for this.

Comment: This is not a site where requests for code are welcome, I'm afraid. I've voted to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to encrypt any file.  The difficult part of your question is if you really want the resulting output to still be an image, rather than a random seeming array of bytes.  Image files have strict formats while encrypted files appear to be random and unformatted.

It is not clear, but you may be wanting something like [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), where one image is hidden inside another.  The hidden file can either be your plain image, or the encrypted version of your image.  If you hide the encrypted version, then obviously you will need to decrypt it before you can display it.

Comment: I get your point, i was a vb.net programmer before. I have experienced doing encrypting of passwords before saving it to database, but still when the user enters their passwords, on the user side, they would not realized that their passwords are saved in different characters on the back end, I was thinking if this situation is also applicable in my case. If I can encrypt the image saved on the Iphone so that no one can view that signature image except my application. Maybe a code that will encrypt the physical file, and a code that decrypt the image on my code, but stays encrypted on my mobile